# How to Get the difference between the two date values in Mongo criteria?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, criteria

How to Get the difference between the two date values in Mongo criteria and return value must be the difference of two date(i.e 10.01.2015 firs date and 20.01.2015 is second date) I need the value as 10 ? can any one help me how to get this in java using spring framework critieria?)

Answer (score 1):

From this article [What's new in Spring Data MongoDB 1.4 M1](http://spring.io/blog/2013/12/04/what-s-new-in-spring-data-mongodb-1-4-m1), you can use the `andExpression` to get the difference between the two date values:

```
.andExpression("endDateTime - startDateTime").as("duration")
```

As an example (untested):

```
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation.*;

TypedAggregation<Trip> agg = newAggregation(Trip.class,
  match(Criteria.where("userId").is("54e5cead3ab5c1dd97422d86")),
  project("endDateTime", "startDateTime")
    .andExpression("endDateTime - startDateTime").as("duration")
);

AggregationResults<DBObject> result = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, DBObject.class);
List<DBObject> resultList = result.getMappedResults();
```

In Mongo shell, you can do the following:

```
db.collection.aggregate( {$match:{ your-match } },
     { $group : { 
         _id : "$userId",
         duration : { $subtract:["$endDateTime", "$startDateTime"]}},
     } } );
```

Answer (score 0):

using spring boot reactive: This will give you duration in mili seconds  like 864000000

```
  List<AggregationOperation> operations = new ArrayList<>();
    operations.add(project().andExclude("_id")
                .and(ArithmeticOperators.valueOf("duration")
                .subtract("startDateTime"))
                .as("endDateTime"));
    operations.add(groupOperation);
 
    //response
    reactiveMongoTemplate.aggregate(newAggregation(operations), "collName",
                Class.class);
```

Answer (score -2):

Rather than using minus operation inside projection, I will suggest you to use ArithmaticOperation.Subtract inside projection pipeline.

```
ProjectionOperation projectionOperation=Aggregation.project().and(Subtract.valueOf(Date.from(Instant.now())).subtract("fieldname"));
```

Comment: `Substract.valueOf` takes a `Number` or a `String` as parameters but not a `Date`.

Comment: This does not work. `ArithmeticOperators.Subtract.valueOf` accepts `String`, `AggregationExpression` or `Number`.